# string array inside object array in PowerShell

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm trying to call a function from a C# DLL via PowerShell. It requires an object array as parameter and I need to pass strings inside it, but I don't know how.

What I need to do:

C# version:

```cs
printCustom(new object[] {new string[] {"hello", "its", "working"}});
```

I need to call this function from powershell but how to pass the parameters?

```cs
printCustom([object[]]@(//now?//));
```

Comment: Is `printCustom` a static or instance method?

Comment: `printCustom` is static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the unary array operator `,` to wrap an enumerable type in an array - this will prevent PowerShell from unraveling the string-array when you then construct the array that'll actually get passed to the method:

```
[TargetType]::printCustom(@(,'hello its working'.Split()))
```

Let's test it:

```
# Generate test function that takes an array and expects it to contain string arrays

Add-Type @'
using System;

public class TestPrintCustom
{
  public static void printCustom(object[] args)
  {
    foreach(var arg in args){
      foreach(string s in (string[])arg){
        Console.WriteLine(s);
      }
    }
  }
}
'@

[TestPrintCustom]::printCustom(@(,"hello its working".Split()))
```

Which, as expected, prints:

```
hello
its
working
```

Comment: well, thats kinda strange, im trying your way but apparently the functions doesnt get called anymore, without errors..

Comment: @root823746374 Can you perhaps update your question with the definition of the `printCustom` method?

Comment: Ok so, i found a way to make it working. The solution was to add [object[]] before your array creation. So: `([object[]]@(,'hello its working'.Split()))`

Comment: Just to know, if i would like to pass the strings without using a single string and then split() how should i do it?

Comment: `$stringArray = 'a','b','c' -as [string[]]; [TargetType]::printCustom(@(,$stringArray))`

Comment: So isnt possible to do it in-line?

Comment: @root823746374 sure, it just gets a bit messy/unreadable: `[TestPrintCustom]::printCustom(@(,[string[]]@('a','b','c')))`